# How to Update Qt 5.4.1 to Qt 5.5?

Tags: 15.04, kde, qt, qt5, wayland

I want to update qt 5.4.1 to Qt 5.5 or 5.4.2 because I want to test KDE Plasma on WayLand.

**Note:** Please provide solution that consume least network resources as I have limited bandwidth.
KUbuntu 15.04

Comment: **Note** Please provide your Ubuntu version :)

Comment: KUbuntu 15.04 Updated

Comment: int_ua Yes, I am using Kubuntu 15.04

Comment: Just curious, what are the reasons to update? Is it segfaulting on every connect/disconnect of an external display? https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=341497

Comment: int_ua Because, I want to test Wayland

Answer (score 2):

I advise you to install a virtual machine and install Ubuntu 15.10 indide this environment. Wily includes Qt 5.4.2.

Do not try to update your Vivid system with Qt 5.4.2.

Comment: Very good advice!  **:-)**

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in other answers, this is not really recommended and may cause issues, however, if you really want it, go [HERE](http://www.qt.io/download-open-source/) and download the .run installer or

```
wget download.qt.io/official_releases/online_installers/qt-unified-linux-x64-online.run

chmod +x qt-unified-linux-x64-online.run

~/qt-unified-linux-x64-online.run
```

This will start the `qt 5x` installer.

Comment: And please share your results afterwards :)

Comment: I decide not to give it try as it is around 800MBs. Second, I replied after many days because my laptop bios get corrupted and I fixed it. Thank you everyone. Hope to test it when 15.10 released.

Answer (score 1):

Short: not ready yet.

General information is on this page: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/QtTesting

Comment: Ok. Then how to install 5.4.2?

Comment: Well, basic algorithm for software not available in official repositories is 1) Try finding PPAs with newer versions, if that fails - 2) Try checking for package availability on official webpage and if that fails - 3) Try building and installing from sources. But that can be quite challenging, unfortunately.

Comment: Looks like Mark found 2) in the other answer, please share your results if you decide to try it.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is totally based on my experience,and the same reason why I'm here,Searching for this same answer.
Well now I have figured it out for me.

http://www.qt.io/download-open-source/

Just visit the link and download the offline installer for your machine and go through the simple click steps.I'm using ubuntu 14.04 and it worked for me pretty fine.